# Split a jar file into two different jar files

Tags: maven, maven-2

I am trying to split my jar file into two different jar files. For example, If I have a jar file that has:

src

-com

--myExample

---package

----java-classes

----interfaces

Manifest

maven

-pom.xml

Manifest.MF

"-" represents the hierarchy of the folders

I want to put interfaces in a different jar file and the rest of them in a different jar file.. And then combine the two jars into one zip file. How can I achieve this in Maven ?

Comment: Well there is a soft principle in maven one project for one artifact. So I suppose you should create two separate projects an api and an impl. This is the easiest way, the official maven way. I think it is possible to create multiple artifacts from one maven projects, but it is usually not so easy.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to do that?  I ask because it isn't "the Maven way" as Andras mentioned.  And Maven doesn't make it easy to do things in a way other than the Maven way.

If you absolutely most do this, [Sonatype describes how](http://www.sonatype.com/people/2010/01/how-to-create-two-jars-from-one-project-and-why-you-shouldnt/).  You notice that they also say you shouldn't do this.

You really should split into two projects.

Comment: I wanted to do so as it is a company standard. But I finally used "antrun" maven plugin to achieve this. Thanks for your answer though.